# Minecraft Forge - Container slots offset?

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I am creating a new mod that has a container. The issue is that the inventory slots are offset by 7. It seems like the server thinks the first column is where the second-to-last column, and the second column is where the last column is. Here is some code. The classes should be included.

```
public class GuiHandler implements IGuiHandler {
    public Object getServerGuiElement(int ID, EntityPlayer player, World world, int x, int y, int z) {
        if (ID == 0) {
            return new ContainerGenerator(player.inventory, (TileEntityGenerator) world.getTileEntity(x, y, z));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Object getClientGuiElement(int ID, EntityPlayer player, World world, int x, int y, int z) {
        if (ID == 0) {
            return new GuiGenerator(player.inventory, (TileEntityGenerator) world.getTileEntity(x, y, z));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The container class

```
public class ContainerGenerator extends Container {
    private TileEntityGenerator tileEntity;
    private int count;

    public ContainerGenerator(InventoryPlayer inventory, TileEntityGenerator tileEntity) {
        this.tileEntity = tileEntity;
        this.tileEntity.openInventory();
        this.count = tileEntity.getCount();
        this.addSlotToContainer(new Slot(tileEntity, 0, 27, 47));
        this.addSlotToContainer(new Slot(tileEntity, 1, 134, 47));
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                this.addSlotToContainer(new Slot(inventory, j + i * 9 + 9, 8 + j * 18, 84 + i * 18));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            this.addSlotToContainer(new Slot(inventory, i, 8 + i * 18, 142));
        }
    }
// some other random code
```

And some relevent tile entity overrides (there is some other random code)

```
@Override
public void readFromNBT(NBTTagCompound nbt) {
    super.readFromNBT(nbt);
    this.count = nbt.getInteger("count");
    NBTTagList tagList = nbt.getTagList("items", 10);
    this.items = new ItemStack[2];
    NBTTagCompound compound = tagList.getCompoundTagAt(0);
    byte slotId = compound.getByte("slot");
    if (slotId >= 0 && slotId < 2) {
        items[slotId] = ItemStack.loadItemStackFromNBT(compound);
    }
    compound = tagList.getCompoundTagAt(1);
    slotId = compound.getByte("slot");
    if (slotId >= 0 && slotId < 2) {
        items[slotId] = ItemStack.loadItemStackFromNBT(compound);
    }
}

@Override
public void writeToNBT(NBTTagCompound nbt) {
    super.writeToNBT(nbt);
    nbt.setInteger("count", count);
    NBTTagList list = new NBTTagList();
    if (items[0] != null) {
        NBTTagCompound compound = new NBTTagCompound();
        compound.setByte("slot", (byte) 0);
        items[0].writeToNBT(compound);
        list.appendTag(compound);
    }
    if (items[1] != null) {
        NBTTagCompound compound = new NBTTagCompound();
        compound.setByte("slot", (byte) 1);
        items[1].writeToNBT(compound);
        list.appendTag(compound);
    }
    nbt.setTag("items", list);
}

@Override
public int getSizeInventory() {
    return items.length;
}

@Override
public ItemStack getStackInSlot(int slot) {
    return items[slot];
}

@Override
public ItemStack decrStackSize(int slot, int amount) {
    if (items[slot] == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (items[slot].stackSize == amount) {
        ItemStack itemStack = items[slot];
        items[slot] = null;
        return itemStack;
    } else {
        ItemStack itemStack = items[slot].splitStack(amount);
        if (items[slot].stackSize == 0) {
            items[slot] = null;
        }
        markDirty();
        return itemStack;
    }
}

@Override
public ItemStack getStackInSlotOnClosing(int slot) {
    if (items[slot] != null) {
        ItemStack itemStack = items[slot];
        items[slot] = null;
        return itemStack;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void setInventorySlotContents(int slot, ItemStack stack) {
    items[slot] = stack;
    if (stack != null && stack.stackSize > getInventoryStackLimit()) {
        markDirty();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** screenshots. Notice which slots are highlighted if any.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

[image: Screenshot 4]

[image: Screenshot 5]

[image: Screenshot 6]

Sorry for the lengthy post. I'm new to modding, so it is hard for me to pin point the issue exactly.

Comment: And yes, the Tile Entity class extends TileEntity and implements IInventory.

Comment: can you include a screenshot with what you mean the server thinks things are different?

Comment: There are other minor weird behaviors, but I don't have a good recording software, so I decided to point out this particular issue.

Comment: So, you place it in slot 1 and then it gets put in slot 7? Hmmmh, now in your write to nbt and read from nbt, can you do a log.info(compound)? just so you can see when the nbt data is called, and when its written how its written.

Comment: I'll write back within the next couple of days, when I can test it.